# Unsalvagable reasons bug for deleted question

Tags: bug, review-queues

Today I reviewed an item in the Triage queue that was clearly off-topic.  I selected "Unsalvagable" but did not get the standard set of review options.  I could only select from 3 options (spam, abusive, needs a moderator).

I selected the option to pass it onto a moderator, saying that it was off-topic (and my reasoning).  In my "helpful flags" I can see the question was put on hold, and then deleted.  I assume this all occurred in a very short time, and during the time I reviewed the item.

Right now I have a pending flag for a question that no longer exists.

[image: Flag]

Is this a bug, in that I should see the full list of close options even if the question has been closed?  It seems a little redundant if the question at that point was already closed, but still, the current situation sees users given a very restricted set of close reasons.  In this case, it was not spam or abusive so I had no choice but to pass it onto a moderator.

I suspect this scenario is a very rare occurrence.  Just to clarify, I simply read the question then submitted my close reason.  This would have been all within a minute, or two at most.  The question (from memory) was short and the problem was obvious.

Comment: Surely the question was already deleted by the time you got to the "why is it unsalvageable" page.  So you only got the 'alert the authorities' options.  Next time this happens you'd probably favor just skipping it.

Comment: @HansPassant - Agreed that skipping is appropriate now I have seen the bug, but not so obvious if this is the first time you have come across the issue.  I doubt this is a regular occurrence, but thought I would raise it regardless.  Unless there is a quick fix I can't see this being fixed (or high on any priority list).

Comment: I agree that it would be more helpful to have better indications that the post has been deleted (besides just the lack of flagging options in the flag menu).